# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'display'

Tags: python, pygame

Im working on a MVP for a rogue like, and I encountered an error that doesn't happen whenever i do it on anything else.

```
import pygame,sys,os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init


MOVERATE = 10
WINDOWWIDTH = 500
WINDOWHEIGHT = 500
def terminate():
     pygame.quit()
     sys.exit()

playerRect = pygame.image.load('Test_Block.png')
playerImage = playerRect.get_rect()

WHITE = (255,255,255,0)

WindowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.update()


WindowSurface.fill(WHITE)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()



while True:



 moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
 playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWHEIGHT / 2),(WINDOWWIDTH / 2)


 for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
           terminate()


      if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == ord('a'):
                     moveRight = False
                     moveLeft = True
                 if event.key == ord('d'):
                     moveLeft = False
                     moveRight = True
                 if event.key == ord('w'):
                     moveDown = False
                     moveUp = True
                 if event.key == ord('s'):
                     moveUp = False
                     moveDown = True

                 if event.type == KEYUP:
                     if event.type == K_ESCAPE:
                         terminate()
                     if event.key == ord('a'):
                          moveLeft = False
                     if event.type == ord('d'):
                          moveRight = False
                     if event.key == ord('w'):
                          moveUp = False
                     if event.key == ord('s'):
                          moveDown = False


 if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
      playerRect.move_ip(-1 * MOVERATE,0)
 if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
      playerRect.move_ip(MOVERATE,0)
 if moveUp and playerRect.top >0:
      playerRect.move_ip(0,-1 * MOVERATE)
 if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
      playerRect.move_ip(0,MOVERATE)

 WindowSurface.blit(playerImage,PlayerRect)
 pygame.display.update()
 mainClock.tick(30)
```

When I run this, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peterbrown/Desktop/data/Rogue/Rogue.py", line 32, in <module>
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWHEIGHT / 2),(WINDOWWIDTH / 2)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'topleft'
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with this, as well as how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mixed up your variable names here:

```
playerRect = pygame.image.load('Test_Block.png')
playerImage = playerRect.get_rect()
```

I think what you wanted instead is:

```
playerImage = pygame.image.load('Test_Block.png')
playerRect = playerRect.get_rect()
```